# Multiple data row columns per line

Tags: sql, birt

I am trying to display a single column from a data set but spread out across a single row.  For example:

```
[Row1] [Row2] [Row3]
[Row4] [Row5] [Row6]
```

Instead of:

```
[Row1]
[Row2]
[Row3] etc.
```

The data set needs to be joined with another table based on column from an outer table which means, AFAIK, cross tabs are out of the question as you can't use data set parameters with them.  There is not a limit to how many rows there will be in a single data set but I want to have 3 row columns per line.

I can modify the data set query however I can only use plain old SQL in those queries except for creating temporary tables or creating anything "new" on the server side - a BIRT-only solution would be more desirable however.

Comment: Why does the query need to use the compound-row format?  If it's just a display formatting thing, that should be handled by whatever code sends the query.

Comment: The parent table has multiple unique rows in the child table (the one where I need to format 3 rows/line).  An application fills the tables, and BIRT queries those tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the query to output

```
1 1 [Row1]
1 2 [Row2]
1 3 [Row3]
2 1 [Row4]
2 2 [Row5]
2 3 [Row6]
```

into a temporary table `tmp`, then you could query that using something like

```
select col1, col3 from tmp into tmp1 where col2 = 1;
select col1, col3 from tmp into tmp2 where col2 = 2;
select col1, col3 from tmp into tmp3 where col2 = 3;
select tmp1.col3, tmp2.col3, tmp3.col3 from tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 where tmp1.col1 = tmp2.col1 and tmp1.col1 = tmp3.col1;
```

You could generate `col1` and `col2` using `rownum`, but it's non-standard, and it requires the output of the original query to be sorted properly.

**Edit:**

If you can't use a temporary table, I assume you can use subqueries:

```
select tmp1.col3, tmp2.col3, tmp3.col3 from
  (select col1, col3 from (ORIGINAL_QUERY) where col2 = 1) as tmp1,
  (select col1, col3 from (ORIGINAL_QUERY) where col2 = 2) as tmp2,
  (select col1, col3 from (ORIGINAL_QUERY) where col2 = 3) as tmp3
where tmp1.col1 = tmp2.col1 and tmp1.col1 = tmp3.col1;
```

and hope the optimizer is smart.

Comment: Unfortunately, creating a temporary table to perform any work won't be allowed.  I'll edit the question to make that clear.